# WDK 10 In Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, driver, configurationmanager

I need someone who is familiar with the configuration manager in visual studio 13.

I am trying to build a driver using WDK10 (It is kind of like a beta download on the microsoft site), but after downloading SDK10 and WDK10, the configuration is not in my Visual Studio 2013. Is there a way to get it into the configuration manager manually? I was thinking it did not go in because I also have WDK8.1 . I don't want to uninstall WDK8.1 because windows 10 is not popular yet.

Update: I decided to download Windows 10 and downloaded Visual Studio 2015. And now when I try to build my Kernal Mode Driver in WDK10, the Target Platform Version is correct (10.0.10069.0), but the only Platform toolset available is Visual Studio 2015 (v140) when I want something like WindowsKernalModeDriver10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the **Windows SDK for Windows 10** and **Windows Driver Kit for Windows 10** are set up to use VS 2015 (currently VS 2015 RC).

You can try using them with an older toolset like VS 2013 by creating .props files. See the [Visual C++ Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/23/using-the-windows-8-sdk-with-visual-studio-2010-configuring-multiple-projects.aspx) for an overview, but keep in mind the directory layouts of the SDK/WDK have changed.

Comment: When I try to build my Kernal Mode Driver in WDK10, the Target Platform Version is correct (10.0.10069.0), but the only Platform toolset available is Visual Studio 2015 (v140) when I want something like WindowsKernalModeDriver10

Comment: ``v140`` is the VS 2015 compiler. There was a brief time when Platform Toolsets were created for various combinations of toolsets and newer SDKs, this isn't really a good practice so they stopped it. Once you've installed the WDK10, you should have access to the ``include\%ver%\km``, ``include\%ver%\wdf``, ``lib\%ver%\km``, and ``lib\%ver%\wdf``  folders that are what you need to build a Kernel Mode Driver.